# Zend_Form_Element from Zend_Config_Ini

Tags: forms, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-form-element

Currently I am loading form element definitions from an ini file that looks like this as an example:

```
[tickets] ; tablename
ticket_number.name = "ticket_number"
ticket_number.type = "text"
ticket_number.label = "Ticket ID: "
ticket_number.options.validators.alnum.validator = "alnum"
ticket_number.options.validators.strlen.validator = "StringLength"
ticket_number.options.validators.strlen.options.min = "6"
ticket_number.options.validators.strlen.options.max = "20"

assigned_date.name = "assigned_date"
assigned_date.type = "text"
assigned_date.label = "Entered Date: "
```

Now lets say I have a form element (select / dropdown box), and I want to load the options from a database (lookup table), is there a way to automatically configure that within the form elements ini config, or does that have to be done within the form class upon creation of the element?

Comment: There is no problem in updating the config_ini object. There is no such thing like automatic, though. It will be up to you to update the object with the information from the database.

Comment: Yah, the more I look at it the more I realize that the only way to create the options for a selectbox is through code within the form class itself.  I was just hoping to be able to link the database lookup table to the dropdown box through the config file.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are ways to do this, the question is whether you actually want to do this.

Possible ways to do it:

1. Create your own smart select element, which has the ability to build a `multiOptions` list based on some option values which you provide in your ini file.
2. or, before creating the form instance, inject the `multiOptions` values into the `Zend_Config` file.
3. or, after you've created the form instance, set the multiOptions using `$form->getElement('name')->setMultiOptions(array(..))`